# C++ std::function stored in vector doesn't work

Tags: c++, function, c++11, vector, bind

The following code works:

```
float value = 3.0f;
auto f = std::bind(&MyClass::doSomething, this, value);
f();
```

However as soon as I try to store the function in an std::vector it won't let me call the function:

```
float value = 3.0f;
auto f = std::bind(&MyClass::doSomething, this, value);

std::vector<std::function<void(float)> > list;
list.push_back(f);
list.back()();
```

This is the compiler error:

```
No matching function for call to object of type 'value_type' (aka 'std::__1::function<void (float)>').  Candidate function not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided.
```

I haven't been stumped like this in a while.  The same issue arises if I try to bind a lambda to the float value instead of using a member function too.

Comment: Please wind this back a bit and tell us the goal. I think that you have approached the problem from the wrong angle. There is an easier solution

Comment: Um, the first one has no `std::function` involved?  And the second one has an error before the last line of code, and that error requires no `vector` to be involved.   Examine `std::function<void(float)> f2 = f;`  I'm guessing `MyClass::doSomething` doesn't take two floats?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you say that the `std::function` object takes one argument, but you don't provide an argument when calling the function object. In fact, the callable object returned by `std::bind` *doesn't* take any arguments so neither should the `std::function` object:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()> > list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the function type in vector requires a float you are not giving. Try with `std::vector<std::function<void(void)> >` instead.